# The word parsimonious

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Does the word have negative connotation or can it be used as a compliment?

Comment: Where would it be used? I doubt many people know such a word off-hand.

Comment: @user3169 I am thinking to say it to my boss, who I assume is educated person.

Comment: @user3169 do you think  a native speaker of English person who graduated from average university does not know that word?

Comment: I meant the average population (random person on the street), as you did not include any context or who you would use the word with. I can't speak to what words a university graduate (outside of liberal arts) might know. I just think there might be less chance of a misunderstanding if you could use a more commonly used word. Your question really should include some examples to indicate your intended usage.

Answer (score 5):

It is a value judgment but not necessarily pejorative. It certainly has non-pejorative senses. We can speak of parsimonious consumption of limited resources, or a parsimonious logical argument.